# inline django admin loop cleaned_data

Tags: python, django

I want to validate all dates which come in inline and I am developing the code below:

```
class CarDetalleForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CarDetalleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        super(CarDetalleForm, self).clean()

        for x, row in enumerate(self.cleaned_data):
            date = row['car_carideal-{}-date_0'.format(x)]
            //here may be more than one variable to validate date

            .... validations dates ....

        return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = CarDetail
        fields = ['group', 'date']
```

but I have the following error (where the variable is assigned "date"):

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

then I'm doing something wrong or that line does not correspond 
anyone have idea how to make the loop to validate all dates? 
Thank you for your help.

PS: sorry for my English: P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here. A form's `cleaned_data` is a dictionary, and iterating over a dictionary gives you the keys. That means that `row` at each iteration of the loop is a string, not a dictionary which itself has keys.

Are you perhaps also using a formset? Maybe you intended to put the code in the formset's clean method, rather than the form's. But if so, that's still the wrong way: each form should clean its own data, by defining `clean_<fieldname>` methods.